# asp .net button column command

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I have the following code on an asp .net project which has a Gridview with the following code:

```
         <Columns>
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Sel" Text="Select"  />
        </Columns>
```

And i am trying to raise an event when it is clicked. I am using the following code in the .cs file:

```
        protected void grdTimes_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Sel")
        {
            lblError.Text = "command";
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately the lblerror.text doesnt changes when a button is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case it worked properly ( I used `Response.Write` too). I'd tell you to try with `Response.Write`, and if it works it may be some wrong set up of your label.

If you want to edit your question with your whole markup, feel free to do it!